# External display is not working under Ubuntu with a Thinkpad W530

Tags: display, thinkpad, nvidia-optimus

I have a new Thinkpad W530. It has a K2000M graphics card (with Optimus) and a Intel Chipset graphic. I can't connect an external display.

Here is what I tried with more or less success.

1) Installed bumblebee: It allows me to run CUDA codes but no external display. Moreover, my graphic card is not detected as the correct one (Q2100 instead of K2000M).

2) Installed hybrid-screenclone and follow this http://sagark.org/optimal-ubuntu-graphics-setup-for-thinkpads/ : It allows to have an external displays but it is very slow and not automatic (no screen detection and no resolution auto-detection).

3) Installed thinkdisp : It is supposed to simplify the previous point but it doesn't work on my computer.

4) Installed new driver 304.37: It is supposed to support my K2000M but it doesn't work. My graphic card is not detected and external display are still not working.

Here is where I am.

NB: the rest (keyboard,wifi) is working perfectly.

I think a lot of people are facing the same problem but there is a lack of unified documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on trying to use Optimus on my Thinkpad W530.  They key is to enter the Bios Setup, go to Display, disable Optimus, and enable the NVidia card only.

This blog post http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html has the super quick instructions for adding a PPA to get the current nvidia driver.

I followed those instructions and am happily using multiple monitors again.